# Bochner's Theorem and Total Positivity

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, pr.probability, rt.representation-theory, matrices

Bochner's Theorem for LCA groups applied to the case of $G = U(1)$ and $G^{\vee} = \mathbb{Z}$ tells us that through the Fourier transform, probability measures on the circle are in bijection with infinite positive semidefinite matrices with $1$s along the main diagonal.  In the case of finite $N \times N$ matrices, we know from convex analysis that these are *correlation matrices*.  Indeed, this corresponds to the case $G = \mathbb{Z} / N \mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow U(1)$ of $N$th roots of unity with its dual group $\mathbb{Z} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z} / N \mathbb{Z} = G^{\vee}$.

Concretely, every *principal* minor of a positive semidefinite matrix has non-negative determinant.  If a matrix satisfies the stronger condition that *every* minor has non-negative determinant, we call it a *totally positive* matrix.

- Is there some nice condition on a positive semidefinite matrix which guarantees it is totally positive?
- Which probability measures on the circle correspond to infinite totally positive matrices with $1$s on the main diagonal?

Comment: The matrix (finite or infinite) obtained by Fourier transform of a measure always has $a_{i,j}=a_{i+1,j+1}$ (circulant matrix), so you don't have a *bijection*, only an injection. Morever for a real measure, they are *complex* (hermitian), unless the measure is symmetric (invariant under $g\mapsto g^{-1}$). Finally shifted principal minors correspond to principal minors of the FT of the orig measure times a characters and this is a positive measure for all characters only if the original measure is a Dirac at the origin. 

Comment: If I have read it correctly, that 1st sentence looks very very wrong... (as per BS's comment)

Answer (score 2):

There is a survey paper http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~fomin/Papers/tptp-color.ps by Fomin and Zelevinsky containing various conditions for total positivity and further references.

Comment: Unless that survey answers one of those two questions, this seems more appropriate as a comment than an answer.

Comment: This survey answers the first question though it is difficult to say whether those total positivity conditions are indeed "nice".